# Error al generar service provider

Tags: laravel

Cree un Service providers que me devuelve todas las provincias desde una API:

El método register contiene lo siguiente:

```
    public function register()
{
    $this->app->when(UpdateStates::class)
        ->needs(Client::class)
        ->give(function () {
            $states = new Client([
                'base_uri' => 'https://apis.datos.gob.ar/'
            ]);

            $response = $states->request('GET', 'georef/api/provincias');

            return (json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true))['provincias'];

        });
}
```

Entonces, cuando sea la Clase UpdateStates, tendria que recibir todas las provincias.

En dicho metodo UpdateStates tengo:

```
   public function handle(Client $states)
    {
        Log::info($states);
    }
```

Esto no me devuelve nada, me tira error. Pero si yo el codigo del service provider lo agrego aca en el método handle este si funciona!

Comment: ¿Qué error aparece?

Comment: Es que espera una instancia de Client y yo devuelvo en el service provider un array de provincias y no se como obtener ese array de provincias en mi metodo handle @Shaz